# XAMPP: killing PID can't stop/run Apache

Tags: apache, xampp

I got a problem when I open XAMPP I see the apache on run mode but its not working. I can't stop it either.

Searched for this, tried to change the port from 80 to 8080 but it doesn't work! I can see it already set to 80 from panel but the files I changed are 8080!!

Here's a screenshot that shows the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7nRn.jpg

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In httpd.conf file change these lines

`Listen 80` to `Listen 81`

`ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:81`

Then open the file httpd-ssl.conf and change

`Listen 443` to `Listen 448`

`<VirtualHost _default_:443>` to `<VirtualHost _default_:448>`

Now close the XAMPP and start again. It should be running. If that doesn't work try changing different ports in both the files.

After changing the ports open the `localhost` in your browser by `localhost:81`

Comment: I tried that before and didn't work, but I noticed now that its working! I think its because I re-start my computer. Thank you so much this answer is what needed to be done to fix the problem.